# google sheet need formula to go backward directory of URL link

Tags: google-sheets

example i have data in colum 
https://www.mybookStore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/279/howtocookegg8.jpg
https://www.mybookStore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/279/howtocookegg9.jpg

i need the formula that can go backward one or two directory in url link, so the result would be:

https://www.mybookStore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/howtocookegg8.jpg
https://www.mybookStore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/howtocookegg9.jpg

i read article about relative file paths: 
Starting with "/" returns to the root directory 
Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards

How to do that on google sheets formula or script, assume i have in A1: https://www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/279/howtocookegg8.jpg

so column B1: would be
https://www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/howtocookegg8.jpg

in C1:
https://www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/howtocookegg8.jpg

i need formula or script that can do that, please help, thanks you.

Comment: The links in your questions are bad. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet and include an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry i am newb for this situation, i read article about relative file paths:

Starting with "/" returns to the root directory 
Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards
Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards 

How to do that on sheets.

assume i have in A1:

www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/279/howtocookegg8.jpg

so column B1: would be
www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/2/howtocookegg8.jpg.

C1: www.mybookstore.com/images/products/80/1020/40422/howtocookegg8.jpg.

i need formula or script that can do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

mmm, ok, (using formulas) first thing you need to remove the file name from the path, then identify how many "/" you got and count the characters so you know how many characters are from the prev-to-last "/", then use =left()-amount_o_chars and then add back the file name.
I suggest you do things step by step. Each step in a different cell using the data from the previous one, once you achieve your goal, integrate the formulas into the last cell.
It can be done, but you have to spend a long time playing with Find(), left(), right(), and any other text formula you can use.